# All caps <title> text - does it effect CTR ? Is it allowed

Tags: google, title, title-attribute

by having all your  text in CAPS i presume that there is a slight increase in CTRs, has any one experimented / experienced this ?

Are you allowed to have all caps title text, or is it seen as spammy i know you cant have all caps title text in adwords ppc titles but what about on the page html  ?

Comment: See also: [Does Google hate capitalized words?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/48864/17633)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally never click on sites that scream at me with "FREE!" or all capital letters, or "DOWNLOAD FULL SPEED" or things. I'd imagine that since all of the spam websites do this, you're better off not. `Proper Title Capitalization` is the ideal way to go. Keep your content and titles organic.

The search engines may or not penalize your rankings for it, but visitors surely will be more cautious.

Comment: That's called Camel Case when you uppercase the first letter of each word.

Comment: @Anagio -- Except I was referring to "Title Case" where unimportant words in the middle like "and" or "of" and such are NOT capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

Google doesn't care, [as their searches are not case sensitive](http://www.googleguide.com/interpreting_queries.html), but [all caps is harder for users to read](http://uxmovement.com/content/all-caps-hard-for-users-to-read/). In addition, it looks like you are shouting, and will give the impression that you are unprofessional and turn some visitors off. I think that it will lower the amount of visitors you get, not raise them.

Comment: just had a look around the google guide link you posted, im not sure how relivant that is, seems pretty old just by the google logo in the screen shots they use ..

Comment: @sam what that source is saying is that whether you search google for `google` or `GOOGLE`, the results will still be the same.