# Does Google hate capitalized words?

Tags: seo, google

I've read around in the past that Google frowns on all caps like "THIS IS MY WEBSITE". But, I wanted to know if they also frown upon capitalized words in general, like in a case like where a name is supposed to be completely capitalized.

Like if a brand had explicitly established itself as all caps because of general words that it may be composed of.

Example: "THE SUN" rather than the typical saying in sentences: "...the sun..."

```
<title>THE SUN - Content, Word & More</title>
```

Does Google punish for specific capitalization like this, or is only for excessive usage and sentences?

Comment: All caps might be rude in chat, but I see no reason why Google would care in web page content or title links, etc. Can you link to somewhere these suggestions have been made?

Comment: See also: [All caps <title> text - does it effect CTR ? Is it allowed](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/31279/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google might associate all caps text chunks with low quality because it's a childish, unprofessional way to write. Avoid those.

**You are fine to use capitalization with specific words**, however, as it doesn't say anything negative about your writing style in general.

Answer (score 0):

Google says nothing about capitalization with specific words. Instead of it, it says about users' interest. If it is useful for visitors - make it and Google will respect your site.

Google says only about capital letters if URL:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4TKJwvTu50